# I am trying to execute a program but its give error based on wine datasets using neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to execute a program but its give error based on wine datasets using neural networks

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

I get an error 'CalledProcessError '

````
<ipython-input-8-846d8ac0593c> in <module>()
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 from subprocess import check_output
----> 5 print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    436         if check and retcode:
    437             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 438                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    439     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    440 

CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '../input']' returned non-zero exit status 2.```
````

Answer (score 0):

A CalledProcessError will be raised if any non-zero exit code is returned by your called process.

If that is okay in your python code, you can except the CalledProcessError and get any information from within its attributes especially the output attribute. (Look up this error in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for more information.)

```
import subprocess
output = None
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = e.output
```

and then you can print these outputs.